# Generic java class that stores comparables

Tags: java, generics, comparable, nested-generics

I have a generic java class that stores comparables:

```
public class MyGenericStorage<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    private T value;

    public MyGenericStorage(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    //... methods that use T.compareTo()
}
```

I also have an abstract class called Person:

```
public abstract class Person implements Comparable<Person>
```

and two concrete subclasses, Professor and Student:

```
public class Professor extends Person
public class Student extends Person
```

now when I want to create a MyGenericStorage like so, I get an error:

```
//error: type argument Student is not within bounds of type-variable T
MyGenericStorage<Student> studStore = new MyGenericStorage<Student>(new Student());

//this works: 
MyGenericStorage<Person> persStore = new MyGenericStorage<Person>(new Student());
```

I think this is because I have a fundamental problem with understanding generics. Can someone explain this to me, and also, how to fix it?

EDIT:

I have changed MyGenericStorage to the following:

```
public class MyGenericStorage<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

and now it seems to work. Can someone explain why?

Comment: What if you change it to `public class Student extends Person implements Comparable<Student>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can fix this with the following declaration for MyGenericStorage:

```
class MyGenericStorage<T extends Comparable<? super T>> { …
```

This means that `T` must have a `Comparable` implementation that accepts some supertype of `T`. In the case of `Student` and `Professor`, the supertype represented by the bound (`?`) is `Person`.

---

*Update: "now it seems to work. Can someone explain why?"*

Well, I tried in my original answer, but let me give it another shot.

`? super T` means "some supertype of T". Suppose `T` in this case is Student. So, Student must implement Comparable "for some supertype of Student"

`Student` extends `Person`, which implements `Comparable<Person>`. So, Student does indeed implement Comparable "for some supertype of Student".

If you have questions about Java Generics, the best place to start is [Angelika Langer's FAQ.](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html) In this case, [the entry about bounded wild-cards](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TypeArguments.html#What%20is%20a%20bounded%20wildcard?) may be helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, I didn't see your answer at the time I edited the question :-)

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that `Person` extends `Comparable<Person>`, so it's ok, but `Student` extends Person and thus **it extends `Comparable<Person>` not `Comparable<Student>`**.

In your constraint you are saying `<T extends Comparable<T>>`, thus they must be the **exact same type**. Derived types **are not acceptable**.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class MyGenericStorage<T extends Comparable<T>>
```

The above requires you to have the type given to the generic class to extend a class which is omparable with itself. In short, you're saying that `Person` must implement `Comparable<Student>` and `Comparable<Professor>`. That's why it can't be used.